# EditText with images

Tags: android, android-edittext, imagespan

I have EditText and I have  ImageSpan in my activity i have image view when choosing a picture from the gallery it goes to the imageView then when I click on the image view the image goes to the edit text now my problem is  let say i added 6 picture side by side on the 7 picture it goes to the second line of the edit text **BUT** the 6 picture from line one disappears . I tried to press enter after picture number 6 it goes to new line without deleting the pictures but when it goes automatically it disappears.

```
  SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(txtSpeechInput.getText());
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(drawable), selectionCursor - " ".length(), selectionCursor, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    txtSpeechInput.setText(builder);
    txtSpeechInput.setSelection(selectionCursor);
```

Comment: Seems like the 6th image is lost cause the textview changes its size to fit the 7th pic (similar to word wrapping). That does not happen when you press enter cause it changes line. try to fit in a scrollview if you don't want to wrap your images. Or even force it to change line after N number of images (depending on screen size)

Comment: my editText actually is in scrollView ,, even after 5th img if wrote text and change the line they disappears

Comment: **NO ONE COME ON PEOPLE**?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to prevent the editext from wrapping?

```
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:lines="1"
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Comment: actually i want to be multi Line edit Text because after the user finish editing picture and texts he can save it as image the whole editText

Comment: You said its ok when you manually adding new line, right? What if you add 4 images, then **\n** for newline ?

Comment: if i manually press the enter button it is working but when it automatically goes to second line the images disappears 
and I want to be multi Line without disappearing